Prerequisites for Harshorne
Are the following books a good prerequisites for Harshorne and a good first steps to modern algebraic geometry?

Eisenbud - commutative algebra
Harris - algebraic geometry
Harris + Eisenbud - geometry of schemes

Does anyone know a better way to learn algebraic geometry?

My opinion is that there is no way anyone could absorb Eisenbud's commutative algebra BEFORE learning about algebraic geometry ; it is simply too dry if unmotivated. Eisenbud does draw links between commutative algebra and algebraic geometry, but they are better understood when one is already somewhat acquainted with algebraic varieties. I would say both go hand in hand: whenever Hartshorne uses some obscure commutatiive algebra result, you can go look it up in Eisenbud, which will have some context.

From my experience, to learn about schemes, it is best to know a basic amount of (old school) algebraic geometry (for which I would rather recommend Shafarevich than Hartshorne, the book is more beginner friendly), the very basics of commutative algebra (ideals of rings, modules, quotients and localization), and the intuition from the basics of manifolds (the philosophy of "to prove this, we can look at a local chart"). Then, just hang on tight, learn the commutative algebra as you go, and DO TONS OF EXAMPLES AND EXERCICES !

The name is Hartshorne.
